# Python: If elif

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

i am trying to create a function that creates an empty coloured picture given the numbers of tiles from createSquareTile(numTiles, prefix)

```
def createSquareTile(numTiles, prefix):
  current = 1
  if current == 1:
    numTiles = requestNumber("Please input a positive number")
    numTilesI = int(numTiles)

    while (numTilesI < 0):
      showError("Your input number" + str(numTiles)+ "is not valid. Do it       again!")
      numTiles = requestNumber("Please input a positive number")

    if (numTilesI > 0):
    current = current + 1
    color = pickAColor()
    return makeEmptyPicture(numTilesI), numTilesI), color)

  elif current > 1:
    previousChoice = requestString("Same size as pervious tile? (Y/N)")

    while (previous != "N") and (previous != "Y"):
      showError("Your input character" + previousChoice + "is not valid. Do it again!")
      previousChoice = requestString("Same size as previous tile? (Y/N)")

    if (previousChoice == "Y"):
      color = pickAColor()
      return makeEmptyPicture(numTilesI, numTilesI, color)
      current = current + 1


    elif (previousChoice == "N"):
      numTilesN = requestNumber("Please input a positive number")
      numTIlesNI = int(numTilesN)
      colorN = pickAColor()
      return makeEmptyPicture(numTilesNI, numTilesNI, colorN)
      current = current + 1
```

According to python, there was a spacing error at

```
elif current > 1:
```

Could somebody please help me what is wrong with my elif statement? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide your error\traceback so we can point you..

Comment: Python's error when trying to load the program was " There was a spacing error in the program. It might be from a previous line, but i think the error is in line 16"

Comment: I can already see a few indentation errors from the code you have pasted. I'm not sure if this is the exact format or if there was just a formatting error, but for example on the line `if (numTilesI > 0):`, you'll have to indent the rest of what comes after that if statement.

Comment: looks like an indentation problem at: "if (numTilesI > 0):"

Comment: You can't have code after a return statement. `current = current + 1`  is unreachable code

Comment: @user3543300  Sorry! there was a formatting error went i posted this. Under "if (numTileI > 0): , everything is indented as it should be.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for spotting that out! However, it didn't remove the error once i have done that

Comment: @Aviad Sorry but that was just a formatting error when i posted this!

Comment: It's not possible for us to reproduce your error without the definitions of your other functions. I'm mostly curious how `current > 1`  is supposed to be reached because you set it to 1 before the first if

Comment: @DarioOngsono replace return makeEmptyPicture(numTilesI), numTilesI), color) -> makeEmptyPicture(numTilesI), numTilesI, color and see if is solved.

Comment: editing the code in question to correct the error makes this useless to future readers so I rolled-back that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your issue:
    return makeEmptyPicture(numTilesI), numTilesI), color)

you should remove the `)` from `numTilesI), color)` and should work because actually your program stops at this line and not moving forward. Performed debug and checks out:

> Connected to pydev debugger (build 162.1967.10)
>   Process finished with exit code 0

**correct will be:**
    makeEmptyPicture(numTilesI), numTilesI, color

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons:

- The line above it has wrong white spaces.
- You mixed `tab` with `space`.
- You have some hidden characters by accident.

Why not first try to remove the white line above it? If all possibilities won't work, please make a comment.

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for helping, i tried all of the above solutions including completely removing the white line above it and it still does not work.

Comment: @DarioOngsono Please upload your code **file** so I can test it.

Comment: Sorry i am new to this site but how do i upload the code file?

Comment: @DarioOngsono just upload it to a web-disk and so on. StackOverflow is unable to upload files.

Comment: Is there a service that you can recommend where i can share my file with you?

Comment: @DarioOngsono Well I am not an American so what we use may be different from what you use. Just use anything you like.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i spotted the error, above elif current > 1:, i have accidentally typed in two extra closing parenthesis in the makeEmptyPicture function.